# Regex to select everything up to a particular character in a URL

Tags: regex, url

How can I select all the characters up to `2` from the following URLs with regex?

```
http://localhost/web/gifts/index.php?catalogue=tshirts&page=2
http://localhost/web/gifts/?page=2
```

Like

```
http://localhost/web/gifts/?page=
http://localhost/web/gifts/index.php?catalogue=tshirts&page=
```

I'd like to change the page number when next page button or any other pages clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.*)(?=\b\d+$)
```

This should do it.See demo.Grab the cpature.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/17

Comment: what if there is a any number?

Comment: @sAs59 `(.*)(?=\d+$)`